# Qt msvc2015 32 bit binaries with msvc 2017 32 bit compiler

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

I need to compile my code with msvc 2017 32 bit compiler. There no pre built binaries of Qt for that compiler. However there are [binary compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrade-why-moving-to-visual-studio-2017-is-almost-too-easy/) between msvc 2015 and 2017. So I have installed Qt msvc 2015 32 bit binaries. Qt Creator gives me the following warning while I trying to adjust Kits:

**The compiler "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.0 (x86)" (x86-windows-msvc2017-pe-32-bit) may not produce code compatible with the Qt version "Qt 5.9.2 MSVC2015 32 bit"(x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-32bit)**

When building:

**Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Error while parsing file ...\project.pro. Giving up.**

Everything works fine if I use Qt msvc2017 64bit binaries with msvc2017 64bit compiler

Comment: What about using MSVC 2015 32bit then?

Comment: Yes, it is a good alternative if it is not possible to use msvc 2017 32 bit. But it seems to be possible

Comment: Qt is available on Windows for 2 type of toolchains MSVC and UWP/WinRT. The error message about `winrtrunner.exe` makes me think that you have mixed MSVC and WinRT in your configuration.

Comment: I have checked version with Qt Maintenance Tool. It is msvc 2015 32-bit, not UWP

Comment: It is just telling you that it does not have a time machine to guess if this is going to work.  It might, VS2017 had no drastic CRT changes.  If you are uncomfortable about it then you need to look for a Qt update.